# re.search webpage source with a carriage return mid string causing errors in Python

Tags: python, youtube, mechanize, python-2.6

Using Python 2.6.6

I'm trying to grab the title of youtube links using mechanize browser, and while it does work on links to actual videos, linking to a channel's page, or their playlists, etc, causes it to crash.

The relevant code segment:

```
ytpage = br.open(ytlink).read()
yttitle = re.search('<title>(.*)</title>', ytpage)
yttitle = yttitle.group(1)
```

The error:

> yttitle = yttitle.group(1)
>   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

The only difference I can see is that a direct video link lays out the title tags on [a single line](https://i.pantsu.cat/qwjmxx.png) in the source whereas every other youtube page seems to put [a carriage return/newline](https://i.pantsu.cat/ddjvpe.png) in the middle of the title tags.

Anyone know how I can get around that carriage return, assuming that is the problem?

Cheers.

Comment: then I guess the better way is NOT to use regex? try to use a html parser instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `re.DOTALL` flag, which will make `.` match everything including a newline.

[Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.DOTALL)

So your second line of code should look like:

```
yttitle = re.search('<title>(.*)</title>', ytpage, re.DOTALL)
```

By the way to extract data from webpage it might be easier to use [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).